# I have written below code to access oci bucket and its objects but getting error

Tags: python, bucket, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

```
import oci

bucket_name = "BACKUP_W_STAGE"

signer = oci.auth.signers.InstancePrincipalsSecurityTokenSigner()

client = oci.object_storage.ObjectStorageClient(config={"region": "us-phoenix-1"}, signer=signer)

objects = client.list_objects(bucket_name)

for object in objects:
    print(object.name)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oci_bucket.py", line 13, in <module>
    objects = client.list_objects(bucket_name)
TypeError: list_objects() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bucket_name'
```

Getting above error, can someone please help to solve this issue.

Comment: [RTFM](https://oracle-cloud-infrastructure-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/object_storage/client/oci.object_storage.ObjectStorageClient.html#oci.object_storage.ObjectStorageClient.list_objects)

Answer (score 0):

`list_objects` has two required arguments - the namespace name and the bucket name:

```py
# namespace_name should be initialized somehow, similar to bucket_name
objects = client.list_objects(namespace_name, bucket_name)
```